# How did Ravio return to Lorule?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

At the ending of Link between worlds, Ravio comes to Lorule to

> stop Hilda.

But how did he come, if Link had the magical bracelet thing?

Answer (score 2):

I searched for this too (for hours) but there is no picture which shows Ravio wearing another bracelet and no information source which says something about his ability to switch between the worlds.

It's not a answer but a suggestion:

Look at this picture of Ravio:

[image]

As you can see Ravio wears a belt with a green rubin implemented, maybe (!) this belt also has some magic abilities to switch between worlds or Ravio just has another item inside his big bag. I mean he got a Hammer, a firestaff, an icestaff, etc. inside... maybe there's another item that nobody knows about.

I think there will be no 100% sure answer on this question unless Shigeru Miyamoto will answer it.